# Redirecting user to login page if principal is null in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

How to redirect a user to login page if a principal from `SecurityContextHolder` is found null in **service** layer (any place)?
I suppose it should be some interceptor or filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the time the request enters the service layer the Security Context should already be populated by one of the configured filters in your security filter chain. If it is not populated, it means either that the security filter chain is not properly configured, or the request URL is not protected by any of the configured filter chains. Check if the `pattern` attribute is present on the `http` element in your security config and if it matches the request url.

The filter that is responsible for handling an unauthenticated request is the `ExceptionTranslationFilter` that will call the configured `AuthenticationEntryPoint` to initiate the authentication process.
The default namespace configuration (`<security:http auto-config="true"...`) sets up this filter with a `LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint` that will redirect the user to the login page.

Comment: I understand this. But what can be a problem when user can still navigate through controllers even if principal is not found? Sometimes it happens on Tomcat when database connection failed and is trying to be restarted due to file changes and hot redeployment. Used Spring MVC + Hibernate + JSP.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "even if principal is not found"? If the `UserDetailsService` is unable to load the user object (which is basically the principal) due to DB connectivity problems, the request will normally never get authenticated (other than anonymous). Consequently your controllers shouldn't receive the request for processing if security is properly configured. Please update your question with concrete details (configuration, exact description of the problem, exception stack traces, etc).

Comment: No worries, it should be different question later. Thanks.